# Get row name if the accumulated sum is the NEAREST to 30 and reset the sum again

Tags: google-sheets, sum, row, array-formulas, accumulate

I have a table with 2 columns: input and length. [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MxdFBb4URCO99EkuTn78oZVSd7iQwfoipwkh1nAOzmo/copy) of the example sheet.

**The Ask**
I want to output the row numbers in a single formula if the accumulated sum of the "Length" `B2:B` is the **closest** to 30, Reset the sum, and do the same.

the desired result is shown in **`C2:C`**

**Example**

`C2` = sum of `$C1:C1` is 8  and sum of `$C1:C2` is 18 >>>> *Do Nothing*
`C3` = sum of `$C1:C2` is 18 and sum of `$C1:C3` is 28 >>> *Do Nothing*
`C4` = sum of `$C1:C3` is 28 and sum of `$C1:C4` is 36>>> *output the row number  `4`* 
---because the following cell `C4` sum `$C1:C4` is => 30
`C4` = sum of `$C1:C4` is 36 "equal or exceeded 30 so **reset** the sum">>>

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and tested this on a custom function, but the issue is that `setFormulas()` applies `=ROW()` as a string value instead of it being detected as a sheets formula, so the script below needs to be manually run.

**Try this script instead:**

```
  function resetthirty() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var data = ss.getActiveRange();
    var values = data.getValues();
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(data.getRow(), data.getColumn() + 1, values.length, 1); 
    console.log(values);
    var sum = 0;
    var acc = [];
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(values[i]);
      if (sum > 30) {
        sum = parseInt(values[i]);
        out.push(["=ROW()"]);
      }
      else out.push([""]);
      acc.push(sum);
    }
    out.shift();
    out.push(['']);
    range2.setFormulas(out);
}
```

**Output:**

NOTE: You need to highlight the values on Column B first, and then run the script because the script uses `getActiveRange()`.

[image]

References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange

Comment: Hi @Diego-Sanchez , Thank you for your response. In my situation, using this method requires more steps. I'll add a bounty once I reach 1,5k.